# Fill the array elements with nil

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[[1,2],[2],[3,4,5,6],[7]]
```

I want to fill the array elements with `nil`. How do I get this result:

```
[[1,2,nil,nil],[2,nil,nil,nil],[3,4,5,6],[7,nil,nil,nil]]
```

I tried:

```
arr=[[1,2],[2],[3,4,5,6],[7]]
l=arr.max_by{|x|x.size}.size
arr.map{|x|x+[nil]* (l-x.size)}
```

Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

An orthodox way would be:

```
a = [[1,2], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7]]
max = a.map(&:length).max - 1
a.each{|a| a[max] ||= nil}
# => [[1, 2, nil, nil], [2, nil, nil, nil], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, nil, nil, nil]]
```

A more interesting way would be:

```
a = [[1,2], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7]]
a.max_by(&:length).zip(*a).transpose.drop(1)
# => [[1, 2, nil, nil], [2, nil, nil, nil], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, nil, nil, nil]]
```

Comment: a.each{|a| a[max] ||= nil}.how to understand it?

Comment: Suppose you executed `a=[1,2]; a[4]=3`.  Then `a #=>[1, 2, nil, nil, 3]`.  Ruby inserts `nil` for each index position skipped over.  Similarly, `a=[1,2]; a[4]=nil; a #=> [1, 2, nil, nil, nil]`.  But what if `a[4]` is already a `non-nil` value?  We wouldn't want to overwrite it with `nil`.  That's why sawa uses `a[4] ||= nil`.  That's shorthand for `a[4] = a[4| || nil`, which will leave `a[4]` unchanged if it is `non-nil`, else will set it to `nil`.

Comment: sawa, I just noticed you could also write `a.each{ |a| a[max]=a[max] }`.  Very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
a = [[1,2],[2],[3,4,5,6],[7]]

longest = a.max_by(&:size).size
a.map { |e| e + [nil]*(longest-e.size) }
  #=> [[1, 2, nil, nil], [2, nil, nil, nil], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, nil, nil, nil]]
```

Another way:

```
b = (0...a.max_by(&:size).size).to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
a.map { |e| e.values_at *b }
  #=> [[1, 2, nil, nil], [2, nil, nil, nil], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, nil, nil, nil]]
```

Lastly (I promise):

```
longest = a.max_by(&:size).size
a.map { |e| f=e.dup; ([nil]*longest).map { f.shift } }
  #=> [[1, 2, nil, nil], [2, nil, nil, nil], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, nil, nil, nil]]
```